# Eclipse Juno Mark as Merged tool throwing NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, nullpointerexception

I am consistently receiving a NullPointerException from Eclipse Juno when I try to "mark as merged" a file I have just resolved all of the merge issue in while in "Team Synchronizing" perspective. It then shows in the Synchronize package view the conflicted file as an update (blue arrow to the left) and my updated file as new (grey arrow with plus sign pointing right) with .tmp appended.

I have used the merge tool in older versions of Eclipse for years just fine and would like to continue using this tool in Eclipse